# Record some data to database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, model

I got a problem
I have a questionnaires website using students as respondents to fill in the matter of the website. The Problem is, when sending data contained on the results of questionnaires to the database,  the data is not recorded in the database.

this is my table named "jawab" as answers record with column: 
'NIS' as Student ID 
'ID_SOAL' as Question ID 
'JAWABAN' as student answers

`| NIS | ID_SOAL | JAWABAN |`
`| ... | ....... | ....... |`

**that table (jawab) still empty**

now in my controller code named "soal" as question controller :

```
public function index(){
$data['title'] = "Kriteria Rumah Masa Depan yang di Inginkan"; // <-- tiltle
$data['form_action'] = site_url('soal/index'); // 

//GET QUESTION
$data['soals'] = $this->Soal_model->getSoal();

    // SEND ANSWERS TO DATABASE  
$JAWABAN = $this->input->post('JAWABAN');
$this->Soal_model->InputJawaban($JAWABAN);

$this->load->view('soal/index', $data);
}
```

my model code named "soal_model" as question model:

```
/* GET ALL QUESTION */      
function getSoal(){
$this->db->select('ID_SOAL, SOAL');
$query = $this->db->get('soal');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
return $query->result_array();
}
}

/* **input students answer to database** */     
function InputJawaban($JAWABAN){
    $data = array(
    'JAWABAN' => $JAWABAN  /* JAWABAN as ANSWER */
    ); $this->db->insert('jawab',$data); 
    }
```

my view code name "index":

```
    <body>  
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $form_action; ?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>SOAL</th>
        <th>JAWAB</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $i= 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($soals as $soal): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $soal['ID_SOAL']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $soal['SOAL']; ?></td>
        <td><input name="JAWABAN<?php echo $i;?>" type="radio" value="1">YA</input>
            <input name="JAWABAN<?php echo $i;?>" type="radio" value="0">TIDAK</input></td>     
            <?php $i++; ?>  
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?> 
</table>
<input type="submit" value="KIRIM"/>
</form>

</body>
```

**the answer just 'YA' and 'TIDAK'**

I have tried, and fail, my database won't record the data
I got **no IDEA**

this is my **goal**

`| NIS | ID_SOAL | JAWABAN |`
`| 001 |    1    |    Ya   |` 
`| 001 |    2    |    Ya   |` 
`| 001 |    3    |  Tidak  |` 
`| 001 |    4    |  Tidak  |`

I hope you understand what I ask
thanks
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can done by using loop over all the questions from the form and their answers but with a slight change in html form and in your model

```
<?php foreach($soals as $soal): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $soal['ID_SOAL']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $soal['SOAL']; ?></td>
<td>
<input name="JAWABAN[<?php echo $soal['ID_SOAL']; ?>]" type="radio" value="1" />YA
<input name="JAWABAN[<?php echo $soal['ID_SOAL']; ?>]" type="radio" value="0" />TIDAK
<input type="hidden" name="question[<?php echo $soal['ID_SOAL']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $soal['ID_SOAL']; ?>" />     
</td>     
<?php $i++; ?>  
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

In above we have assigned all the answers tag name with theirs corresponding question id and another hidden input with name as question and its value containing the question id.

In controller we will pass the post data to model

```
$this->Soal_model->InputJawaban($_POST);
```

In model we get the question id from post data as below and loop through the question and based on question if pick the answer from post data i have used `JAWABAN,ID_SOAL` column to insert data and not sure for data of `NIS` so i put 1 for this column you can change it accordingly

```
function InputJawaban($data)
{
    if (empty($data)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($data['question'] as $key => $qid) {
        $answer = $data['JAWABAN'][$qid]; /* $qid is question id and from that id
        i have picked the answer whose name contains that question id i*/
        $data = array(
            'JAWABAN' => $answer,
            'ID_SOAL' => $qid,
            'NIS'   =>1
        );
        $this->db->insert('jawab', $data);
    }
    return true;

}
```